# regex, string to float number, get rid off other chars

Tags: java, regex

With Stings like `123.456mm` I would like to get one String with the number and the other with the measurement. So in the above case, one String with `123.456` and the other String with `mm`. So far I have this:

```
String str = "123.456mm";

String length = str.replaceAll("[\\D|\\.*]+","");
String lengthMeasurement = str.replaceAll("[\\W\\d]+","");

println(length, lengthMeasurement);
```

The output is:

`123456 mm`

The dot is gone and I can't get it back.
How can I keep the dots?

Comment: You had a problem and you decided to use regex. Now you have two problems.

Comment: Agree with Nit.  This problem probably would be better solved with something like: `Object[] values = new MessageFormat("{0,number}{1}").parse(str); Number quantity = (Number) values[0]; String units = (String) values[1];`

Comment: Wouldn't that fail if "123.456" is used instead of "123.456mm".

Comment: Nope, the units would simply be an empty String.  That said, if you are expecting a value specified with units, I would be wary of allowing a number with no units;  assuming a particular unit of measure has been known to cause [serious trouble](http://www.cnn.com/TECH/space/9909/30/mars.metric/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
String str = "123.456mm";

String length = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]+",""); // 123.456
String lengthMeasurement = str.replaceAll("[\\d.]+",""); // mm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) using below regex and get the matched group from index 1 and 2.

```
(\d+\.?\d*)(\D+)
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/zN6mX8/8)

Try below sample code:

```
String str = "123.456mm";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.?\\d*)(\\D+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Length: " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("Measurement : " + m.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
Length:123.456
Measurement :mm
```

Pattern description:

```
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
    \.?                      '.' (optional (0 or 1 time))
    \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times)
  )                        end of \1

  (                        group and capture to \2:
    \D+                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (1 or more times)
  )                        end of \2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String str = "123.456mm";

String str1 = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");
String str2 = str.replaceAll("\\d|\\.", "");

System.out.println(str1);
System.out.println(str2);
```

Output:

```
123.456
mm
```